# Use Wi-Fi hotspot as "internet input" on router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, dual-band

I have recently purchased and configured two Linksys Business Dual WAN Gigabit VPN Routers (LRT224) [[https://www.amazon.com/Linksys-Business-Gigabit-Router-LRT224/dp/B00GK640D6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1507923227&sr=8-1&keywords=LRT224]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GK640D6).  The router allows me to connect two internet providers for failover protection so that if one of the internet provider's connections goes down, the LRT224 will automatically route traffic to the failover connection.  It seems like that would be a pretty straightforward set-up if I had two **wired** internet connections coming into my router.  But what I'm trying to do is use my one hard wired internet connection from my ISP that feeds into my LRT224 from the modem (what I currently have set up) AND use a Wi-fi router that I have to connect to a wi-fi hotspot and feed that connection to my LRT224 as the failover.

So my question is:  can I use a wi-fi router to connect to the internet and then feed this connection to my LRT224 as the failover?  So this is kind of the opposite of how most people use their wi-fi routers (in most cases, people would connect to their wi-fi router wirelessly and connect to the web from its wired connection to the ISP.  I am trying to have the wi-fi router connect to a hotspot and then use that connection for the internet).  If this is possible, how would I go about using a wi-fi router to make it's connection to a wifi hotspot as the internet connection input to my LRT224?

FYI, the wi-fi router that I have is the LInksys EA9200 AC3200 Tri-Band (https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-EA9200/), but I'd be happy to purchase a different router if it means I could get the failover to work with it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it, but you'll need an access point configured to connect to the WiFi and connected to one of the router's WAN ports.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more?  How can I configure a wifi router to be both an access point and connected to the wifi hotspot?  My understanding is that the wifi router, once placed in bridge mode to be an access point, cannot connect to wifi hotspots.  Hopefully you or someone else can provide some additional instruction (assume I'm using the EA9200 wifi routers). Thanks.

Comment: As I said, you need an access point to connect to the WiFi hotspot. Connect the access point to the router's WAN port.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm not sure that makes much sense to me.  It's an access point for connecting wirelessly to my own router?  How would the access point allow me to connect to some other wifi signal?

Comment: You would use the access point in station mode to connect the router to the hotspot. You would configure the access point as a station on the WiFi network that has the Internet connection and you would connect the access point to the router's WAN port.